# How can I configure Karma to open a browser with command line arguments?

Tags: karma-runner

I'm using the Karma Test Runner and I've configured it to use Chrome and PhantomJS like this:

browsers = ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'];

How can I configure Karma to open these browsers with certain command line arguments, like --diable-web-security in the case of Chrome, and --web-security=no in the case of PhantomJS?

I suppose one option would be to write a custom browser script, but that seems like overkill if there is some feature in Karma I don't know about that handles this case.

Answer (score 23):

Something like this should work:

```js
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['Chrome_without_security','PhantomJS_without_security'],

    // you can define custom flags
    customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_without_security: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--disable-web-security']
      },
      PhantomJS_without_security: {
        base: 'PhantomJS',
        flags: ['--web-security=no']
      }
    }
  });
};
```

More information here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher#configuration

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this in Firefox, IE, Opera too? Btw. Chrome requires now a directory flag too: `"flags": ["--user-data-dir=''", "--disable-web-security"]` and it does not turn off everything. E.g. the x-frame-options header still works.

Answer (score -5):

One solution I found, which may not be the most elegant, is to actually modify Karma's launcher scripts for each browser.  This has solved the problem.

Comment: Could you say exactly what you did?